# Switch case looping on two strings with the same length

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have a switch case that is looping on the length of different strings:
meaning

```
switch(x.GetLength())
{
case 0 // means string length is 0
... and so on


}
```

The problem i am facing is that there are two strings with the same length of 6, So i will have 2 cases with the same number

case 6

case 6

The string in the first case comes always in the form of numbers, does not contain any Letters/ characters

The string in the second case comes always with character P in the beginning of the string.

I want to deffrentiate between the two cases: what i tried is to switch over 
(x.GetLength(), X.GetAt(0))

but it gives an error that the case expression is not constant
otherwise i cannot have two cases with the same number

```
switch(m_strScanned.GetLength(), X.GetAt(0)) // switch over String Length
{
case (6,2): // This case where the 6 digits are all numbers

WTN: if (m_strScanned.Mid(2,1).FindOneOf(".,/*-+ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")>=0) goto Y;
if(m_strScanned.Mid(3,1).FindOneOf(".")>=0) goto X;
else
{
....
break;
}
case (6,'P'):
goto TYPE; // this is where the first digit is P

TYPE: if(m_strScanned.Mid(2,1).FindOneOf("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")>=0)
goto Y;
if(m_strScanned.Mid(3,1).FindOneOf(".")>=0) goto X;

else
{
....
break;
}
```

Is there a solution avoiding if else conditions

Thanks for the help

Comment: why not have your scanner return an enum value rather than a string ?

Comment: `case (6,2)` ought not *compile* (see my answer). Does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution using only a `switch` statement and `case` labels, you have to have one single `case` and then use e.g. `if` inside it to select the correct code:

```
switch (m_strScanned.GetLength())
{
    ...

case 6:
    if (m_strScanned[0] == 'P')
    {
        // Handle this special case
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle this other special case
    }
    break;

    ...
}
```

Comment: but instead of P i want to say, If the first character is one of the alphabets from A to Z, but the function .FindOneOf("ABC...Z") does not help in this case

Comment: @HeshamMahmoud How about using [`std::isupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isupper)?

Answer (score 1):

Hum. I'm amazed this compiles. Case labels need to be compile time evaluable constant expressions, but a constant expression cannot contain the comma operator!

I *think* your (therefore non-standard's compliant) compiler will treat `case (6,2)` as `case 2` and `switch(m_strScanned.GetLength(), X.GetAt(0))` as `switch (X.GetAt(0))` due to how the *comma operator* works. It's even possible (although I think unlikely) that you might have a compiler extension that treats `case (6, 2):` as `case 6: case 2:` and so on. But if you exploit that then you're giving up portability.

There's nothing stopping you from using an `if` block within `case 6` for further descimination, or drop the `switch` entirely in favour of an `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
case 6:
  if('P'==x[0]) {
    // do something
  }
  else {
    // do something else
  }
  break;
```

What's wrong with that?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, but instead of P i want to say, If the first character is one of the alphabets from A to Z, but the function .FindOneOf("ABC...Z") does not help in this case

Comment: You mean something like `if(x[0]>='A' && x[0]<='Z') {
        // do something
      }`

Comment: exactly but instead x[0], the whole string X

Comment: [find_first_not_of](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_not_of/) is what you are looking for. If it's not in"A..Z", then `// do something else`, otherwise `// do something`